MSAL chromium.components.autofill.AutofillProvider causes IllegalStateException in Android 8
I am using MSAL (microsoft authentication library) v5.1.0 for Android and we noticed a couple of crashes on Crashlytics regarding a function on the AutofillProvider being called. The exception is:
Fatal Exception: org.chromium.base.JniAndroid$UncaughtExceptionException: Native stack trace: <REMOVED FOR BREVITY>
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:753)
       at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelSession(IAutoFillManager.java:552)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.cancelSessionLocked(AutofillManager.java:865)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.cancel(AutofillManager.java:708)
       at org.chromium.components.autofill.AutofillProvider.cancelSession(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-636711321:25)
       at J.N.MQGusfGb(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-636711321)
       at Bx.run(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-636711321:3)
       at X20.handleMessage(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-636711321:55)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

As I understand it some function within the chromium WebView triggers the AutofillProvider in an Illegal State. I think it comes from the MSAL login WebView because all my custom logging indicate it happens in the AuthenticationCallback's onSuccess and onCancel.
It happens 100% in Android 8 which is when the AutofillProvider became available in Android (docs).
As far as I can see there are no issues on the MSAL GitHub page that are similar.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
